# Multitenancy in hibernate is too slow

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, multi-tenant

I have created multitenancy application using spring4 hibernate4 and struts2 running in tomcat server. Initially it loading in good speed but when I am refreshing browser it taking long time than expected. (I am thinking that there is a session problem) Please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by replacing

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" abstract="true"
      destroy-method="close" id="abstractDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
</bean>
```

with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
           id="abstractDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks for all